# Authenticate WCF by matching client and server certificate together

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, x509certificate

I am using C#, asp.net application with WCF.

I have created a client certificate ( Client.pfx) and installed in my machine under current user.Then I have created and installed a server certificate ( Server.pfx ) in my WCF hosted machine. Now I need to authenticate from client by matching both client and server certificate together. If there is matching, then it would have to allow the access of methods inside the WCF. How to achieve this?

Comment: Could you give more detail on what you mean by "matching the certificates"? Do both machines have the same certificate?

Comment: To authenticate WCF from client app, we need to match whether the same certificate configured in the WCF hosted server. So if the configured server and client certificate are same, the service is then authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write code to perform certificate authentication - this can be handled by configuration.

From this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648360.aspx

There are a number of ways to specify the location of the certificate.  This example is using the certificate store for the service:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
       <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
       <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
       <serviceCredentials>
           <serviceCertificate findValue="CN=tempCertServer" />
       </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

And this one is using a certificate that is encoded directly in the config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="NewBehavior">
                <clientCredentials>
                    <clientCertificate findValue="CN=tempCertClient"/>
                </clientCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    ...
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://<<service address>>"
            behaviorConfiguration="NewBehavior" binding="wsHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="wsHttpEnpoint1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService"
            name="wsHttpEndpoint">
            <identity>
                <certificate encodedValue="<<Encode Value>>" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Is this for WCF web.config file?

Comment: Yes - yes it is.  Understanding certificates is a big topic - you're going to have to do more than just copy and paste someone's answer from here.  I recommend doing some reading about certificates and WCF configuration.

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about, Praveen, is client certificate authentication. There's a lot written about this, but basically you have two authentication options when using client cert authentication:

One is called ChainTrust, which means the client certificate has as its certificate authority (CA) basis a certificate found on the host.

Another option is called PeerTrust, which means the client auth certificate has a copy found on the host within the LocalMachine\TrustedPeople store on the host.

Or you can use PeerOrChainTrust, which means that if either the Chain or Peer trust is true, the client is allowed in.

It's a huge topic - too big for this little forum, but here's a good starting point for you to start with:

Here's a link; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650785.aspx

Comment: My situation is to create a certificate from client side and send the copy of this certificate to the WCF hosted party for approval just like First Data API works. So what method I need to adopt?

Comment: This method you're talking about is new to me. The dev model I've used allows the WCF service to authenticate the client to the host based on a certificate the client has that matches (based on what I outlined in my answer) a cert found on the host. What you're talking about sounds more like a certificate enrollment process ... I have no idea how you'd make that work.